fill_value='extrapolate', bounds_error=False in interp1d still raise ValueError
I have set the fill_value='extrapolate', bounds_error=False for using interp1d.
f_ca = interp1d(df_Ca['Cap_x'], df_Ca['V'], kind='linear', fill_value='extrapolate', bounds_error=False)

However when I run the code there is still error raised.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[30], line 122
    120 HC_data_diff = len(df_HC)//100*3
    121 df_HC['An_V'] = f_An(df_HC['Q (mAh)'])
--> 122 df_HC['Ca_V'] = f_ca(df_HC['Q (mAh)'])
    123 df_HC['Fit_V'] = df_HC['Ca_V'] - df_HC['An_V']
    125 df_HC['Fit_dV'] = df_HC['Fit_V'].diff(HC_data_diff)
scipy\interpolate\_polyint.py:80, in _Interpolator1D.__call__(self, x)
     59 """
     60 Evaluate the interpolant
     61 
   (...)
     77 
     78 """
     79 x, x_shape = self._prepare_x(x)
---> 80 y = self._evaluate(x)
     81 return self._finish_y(y, x_shape)
scipy\interpolate\_interpolate.py:752, in interp1d._evaluate(self, x_new)
    750 y_new = self._call(self, x_new)
    751 if not self._extrapolate:
--> 752     below_bounds, above_bounds = self._check_bounds(x_new)
    753     if len(y_new) > 0:
...
    783                      .format(below_bounds_value, self.x[0]))
    784 if self.bounds_error and above_bounds.any():
    785     above_bounds_value = x_new[np.argmax(above_bounds)]

ValueError: A value (0.0) in x_new is below the interpolation range's minimum value (16.433608807468445).

Does someone have the same issue and let me know why.
For additional information, I have been using this interp1d winthin a scipy.optimize.minimize function.
# Optimization
result = minimize(Fitting_RMSE, initial_guess, args=input_df_list, method=method)

The ValueError seems to be raised only because that interp1d used within this minimize function (inside the Fitting_RMSE function) while the error is gone if I run outside for the same set of value.

The error is not enough to reproduce your issue, you should provide a [mre].

What version scipy are you using?

Also interp1d is not really supported anymore.

@jared scipy '1.10.1'

@mozway any better suggestion to replace interp1d. I need some thing easy to do linear interpolation and extrapolation. numpy.interp is more troublesome and less easily to use as storing interpolation as an model like tool.

See here for how to achieve linear interpolation with extrapolation.

Do you have somewhere else you call interp1d() with bounds_error=True? As I understand it, there's no way to get this error unless bounds_error is True or None. See here for the code that raises this error: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.14.0/scipy/interpolate/_interpolate.py#L562 Can you post the full traceback?
